# How to toss an object once I hold on to that same object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This isn't in FPS. This is like a top down view game. Do I have to add raycast for the toss?

I thought the code for that is under void toss() but it didn't work. Please help

```
public Transform theDest;
public float throwforce = 300f;


void Update()
{
    pickingoff();
    toss();
}


private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
{
    if(other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().useGravity = false;
            this.transform.position = theDest.transform.position;
            this.transform.parent = GameObject.Find("Destination").transform;
            Debug.Log("Pick up");
        }
    }
}


void toss()
{
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(transform.forward * throwforce);
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().useGravity = true;
        this.transform.parent = null;

    }

}

void pickingoff()
{
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
    {
        this.transform.parent = null;
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().useGravity = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this made in unity ?

Comment: yes. It is in Unity

Comment: did it work ? have u been able to inspect your variables ?

Comment: annnnd it's gone!

Answer (score 0):

To make something move in unity you have to add direction and force to it, and seems you are already doing that, i fear you're getting a reference to the wrong object by the way, try assigning a tag to the object you want to throw and use something like

```
var thingToThrow = GameObject.FindWithTag("ThingToThrow");
thingToThrow.mass = 10f;
thingToThrow.useGravity = true;
thingToThrow.AddForce(transform.forward * throwforce);
```

The other main advantage is that you can inspect what you are adding mass and force to